# Phone front-facing camera is better than one in MBP. Am I missing anything?

Tags: macos, camera, webcam, zoom.app, video-conference

After having to call my significant other using camera build into my MBP 15-Inch "Core i7" 2.2 Touch/2018 ([profile](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.2-15-mid-2018-true-tone-display-touch-bar-specs.html) on everymac.com), I tried calling from my [phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnePlus_6T) and was blown away by how phone video quality is superior to that of my MBP.

**How come?**

This seems to be very counterintuitive. I'd expect my MBP's built-in camera to be far superior than my phone's. Is this not the case?

To do video calls I use Zoom, as well as Facebook Messenger from browser.

Comment: The answer is in your provided links. MacBook camera 720p, phone 1080p

Comment: @Tetsujin true, that kind of makes sense. I was thinking this might be the reason, but still was unsure. Thanks!

Comment: There may also be image processing on the phone to improve the quality which is not found on the MBP. Most phones are not held in the most stable, vibration-free positions that a MBP would be found in, say on a desk or counter.

Comment: The phone is probably also downsampling a long way to reach that; it's 16mp for stills, the MBP is likely only 0.9mp, as it's not designed to be a stills camera at all.